# Is there a way to dump syntax highlighting to a .vim file?

Tags: syntax-highlighting

If I set syntax highlighting rules manually (not in a file), is there a way to save them out to a file? Specifically, the goal is to source this file to restore the syntax highlighting rules later on.

Comment: You should improve the question to make it more clear what you want. Based on the question as it stands now, @romainl has given a good answer. However, as is clear from the (rather childish) discussion between you guys, what you ask is if there is a way to save the highlighting commands to a file for them to be sourced later on. This is really quite different.

Comment: FWIW, I updated the question. I also added a new answer that might be more helpful.

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you want to save to a file. If it's what I think a combination of using the .viminfo and yolenor's answer and adding to .vimrc might do what you want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no command that will save the syntax/highlight definitions to a file that can be parsed to restore the same definitions at a later stage. Or, to be more specific, I do not think that any such command exists. I also do not know of any plugins or addons that will do this.

However, the command history is stored in `~/.viminfo`. Thus, if you want to copy manually typed highlight/syntax commands into a file for later sourcing, you may copy the relevant commands from the command history. Of course, this requires some manual parsing and tweaking, but I think this is the simplest solution to your problem.

For more details, see:
- `:h viminfo`
- `:h 'viminfo'`

Answer (score 12):

You can use `:redir` for that.

Dump highlight definitions:

```
:redir > file
:hi
:redir END
```

Dump syntax definitions:

```
:redir > file
:syntax
:redir END
```

Notes:

- you will probably need to press `G` and `<CR>` to get to the end of the listing if you don't want to go through everything.
- neither method will produce a working syntax script or a working colorscheme, you will need to edit the result anyway.

See `:help :redir`

Comment: Not quite; that just shows what links to what. That's not something that can be loaded back in as a syntax file.

Comment: It is exactly what you asked for: a snapshot of every current `hi`, linked or not. Now, there is no magical command to turn that into a proper colorscheme so you will have to do a bit of editing. And it so happens that Vim is pretty good at editing text.

Comment: That is not what I asked. Being pedantic doesn't help anything; you know what I meant.

Comment: Revenge downvoting doesn't help either.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what you asked. I used that very command to create a flat clone of Solarized and it worked perfectly. If you don't want to dump your `hi whatever` commands don't ask how to dump them and ask what you want.

Comment: `aruaFunction   xxx links to Operator` isn't what I asked for. That doesn't include the `keyword` matches that comprise the `aruaFunction` match. So no, this isn't what I asked for. **Revenge downvoting is being a poor sport**.

Comment: It is all you can get. Once you have that you'll need to edit the result to turn it into an actual colorscheme.

Comment: So you're saying it can't be done? Make that your answer then.

Comment: This should be *choose* as correct answer.

Answer (score 4):

This may be helpful for future readers:

This function returns an executable command which can restore the actual highlight attributes for one highlight group (not fully tested, but it handles linked groups):

```
function! GetHiCommand(group)
    redir => l:output
        silent! exec 'hi' a:group
    redir end

    let l:link = matchstr(l:output, 'links to \zs\w\+')

    if empty(l:link)
        let l:attrs = matchstr(l:output, '\<xxx \zs[^\n]*')
        return printf('hi %s %s', a:group, l:attrs)
    else
        return printf('hi! link %s %s', a:group, l:link)
    endif
endf
```

Example output:

```
:echo GetHiCommand('LineNr')
hi LineNr term=underline ctermfg=243 guifg=#7c6f64

:echo GetHiCommand('MoreMsg')
hi! link MoreMsg GruvboxYellowBold
```